# How do I tie html inputs into my javascript function?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>


    <body>
        <form>
            Birth Year:<br>
            <input type="number" name="birthYear">
            <br>
            Current Year:<br>
            <input type="number" name="currentYear">
        </form>
        <button onclick="calculateAge()">Calculate Age</button>
        <div id="output"></div>

          <script>
          function calculateAge(ghF, xhF) {
          var ghF = "birthYear"
          var xhF = "currentYear"
          return (xhF - ghF);
          } {
           document.getElementByID("output").innerHTML = text;
          };
          </script>
   </body>
```

When I click on the button it should print out "You are x age". Where would I add that text? At the moment nothing happens when I click on the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `getElementById` will return the DOM element having `id` as mentioned argument. `.value` is property of `input` element which will give the value of `input`
>    Instead of returning value, you must set the `innerHTML/innerText` after doing subtraction.

**Note:** You must assign unique `id` attributes to the element to retrieve DOM element.

```js
function calculateAge() {
  var ghF = document.getElementById("birthYear").value;
  var xhF = document.getElementById("currentYear").value;
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = xhF - ghF;
}
```

```html
<form>
  Birth Year:
  <br>
  <input type="number" name="birthYear" id="birthYear">
  <br>Current Year:
  <br>
  <input type="number" name="currentYear" id="currentYear">
</form>
<button onclick="calculateAge()">Calculate Age</button>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function calculateAge() {
          var ghF = document.getElementById("birthYear").value;
          var xhF = document.getElementById("currentYear").value;
 document.getElementById("output").innerHTML="You are " +(xhF - ghF) + " age";
          }
```

[EXAMPLE](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/60dz7fLq/5/)

Answer (score 0):

The function is badly formed.

This will do the trick:

```js
  function calculateAge() {
        var ghF = document.querySelector('[name="birthYear"]').value;
        var xhF = document.querySelector('[name="currentYear"]').value;
        document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "You are "+(xhF - ghF)+" age";
    }
```

```html
<form>
    Birth Year:
    <br>
    <input type="number" name="birthYear">
    <br>
    Current Year:
    <br>
    <input type="number" name="currentYear">
</form>
<button onclick="calculateAge()">Calculate Age</button>
<div id="output"></div>
```